# make the first character lowercase in jsp

Tags: html, jsp

I have an href tag containing particular name.That is in a specified format.(e-Split) .I want to display the string as same as I entered. That means first letter want to be show as small letter.How can I do that?Can anyone help me to find out the result?

Thank you

In jsp

```
<div align="left" style="width: 100%; float: left;margin-left: 120px;"> 
<br>
<a href="https://anylink.com" target="_blank" style="color: #292929; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold">e-Split
</a>    
</div>
```

It shows the output as

> E-Split

Comment: Ya.But That is a platform  to test code.right?

Comment: yes, that is shows the same output.I want show it as e-Split

Comment: Sorry sir,the result is same as when copy the code to my jsp

Comment: I want to show e-Split as e-Split.But my issue is shows E-Split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text-transform is used to change the word's style.They are as follows :

```
p.uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

All character will be capital.

```
p.lowercase {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

All character will have lower case.

```
p.capitalize {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Only first character will get capital.

But in your case, after excuting your words are getting capital so you can ignor this by using none.

```
text-transform:none !important
```

`!important` used to have this property if any other property is coming. Hope it will help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
<div align="left" style="width: 100%; float: left;margin-left: 120px;"> 
<br>
<a href="https://anylink.com" target="_blank" style="text-transform:none !important;color: #292929; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">e-Split
</a>    
</div>
```